# Make required json available in other modules

Tags: node.js, json, configuration, require

I am writing an application that has configuration parameters in a json file. Something like this:

```
// config.json
{
  "httpServer": {
    "port": 3000
  },
  "module1": {
    "setting1": "value1",
    "setting2": "value2"
  },
  "module2": {
    "setting1": "value1",
    "setting2": "value2"
  }
}
```

```
// index.js
const config = require("./config")
const func1 = require("./module1")
const func2 = require("./module2")

// code here
```

```
// module1.js

const config = require("./config")

// use config and define functions

module.exports = {

function: function

}
```

```
// module2.js

const config = require("./config")

// use config and define functions

module.exports = {

function: function

}
```

The problem is that I am requiring this file in every module which makes my code unmaintainable since I need to update every require statement if the filename changes. I am pretty sure that this is not the "correct" way of doing this. Can I require the configuration file once when the program starts and then reference to it in other modules? Or should I pass the configuration file as a command line argument and then use process.argv array when requiring the file? What is the best way of handling situations like these?

Comment: You can use https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config
It allows you to get only the required section from your config, and manage environments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use dotenv package `npm install dotenv --save`,

create a config file

```
//config.env
NODE_ENV=development
IP=127.0.0.1
PORT=3000
```

load the config file

```
//index.js
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config({ path: './config.env' })
```

use it where ever you want

```
//module1
console.log('IP: ',process.env.IP)
```

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I don't really see anything wrong in requiring the config in multiple files. Since you need it, you are requiring it.

If you really don't want to require multiple times, you could consider this

Convert the function style to class style and then inject the config as a dependency to that class

**Main File**

```
const config = require("./config");
const file1 = new File1(config);
const file2 = new File2(config);
```

**File 1**

```
class File1 {
   constructor(config) {
     this.config_ = config;
   }

   someFunction() {
    // use this.config_ here
   }
}
```

**File 2**

```
class File2 {
   constructor(config) {
     this.config_ = config;
   }

   someFunction() {
    // use this.config_ here
   }
}
```

Few advantages of using this approach are:

- better testable as you can mock the config if you want.
- you could also change at one place and you wouldn't need to change other places as you are injecting.